# How to choose in a selection list if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

If there are any spelling mistakes, I am german.

The user of my site should say, in which class of school he is.
Since it is possible that he doesn't go to school any more, I have a radio button.
He says, whether he goes to school or not:

```
<h2>Are you in school?</h2><br>
<input type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="No">I'm not any more in school.<br>
<input type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="Yes">Yes, in class
```

And here's the problem: After "in class" should come a selection list with 1, 2, 3, etc.
But if I make this list

```
<select name="KlasseOption" size="1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    etc.
</select>
```

You can choose one of the selections in the selection list no matter whether the Radio Button Value "Yes" or Value "No" is pressed.
But it should only be possible to change the selcetion list if the Radio Button Value "Yes" is pressed.
If the Radio Button Value "No" is pressed, nobody should be able to change it from the default "--".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using jQuery for easier solution.

**Css solution (for modern browsers only)**

```css
select {
  opacity:0.5;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#radio2:checked ~ select {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:initial;
}
```

```html
<h2>Are you in school?</h2><br>
<input id="radio1" type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="No"><label for="radio1">I'm not any more in school.</label><br>
<input id="radio2" type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="Yes" class="yes"><label for="radio2">Yes, in class</label>

<select name="KlasseOption" size="1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  etc.
</select>
```

**Regular (javascript) cross browsers solution**

**Logic:**

When user check a radio button, you check if it has `.yes` class (Which I added). If so, I enable the dropdown using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').change(function() {
    $('[name=KlasseOption]').prop('disabled', !$(this).is('.yes'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Are you in school?</h2><br>
<label><input type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="No">I'm not any more in school.</label><br>
<label><input type="Radio" name="ClassRadio" value="Yes" class="yes">Yes, in class</label>

<select name="KlasseOption" size="1" disabled>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    etc.
</select>
```

Comment: One last question: Is there a possibility (in the css code) that, if somebody clicks first Value "Yes", choose a class, and clicks than value "No", the class will be resettet to deaufault (e.g. "--")

Comment: No without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript to achieve that. Just check if the value is changed and then disable or enable the select tag.

Comment: 2. Is there a possibility to make this without javascript?

Comment: I can write a test code, but any specific reason you looking for a non-javascript solution?

Comment: I don't use javascript because you can deactive it in every browser. I have tested it in firefox with deactivided javascript and it doesn't worked